# How to declare an expression array in term of other variables in OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

Here is my code:

```
range products = 1..5;

// Variables
dvar float+ P;
dvar float+ Q;

// Expressions
dexpr float produced[products] = [P, Q, P, P+Q, P+Q];
```

The problem is that I can't use the `produced` expression because I get the error:

```
Index out of bound for array "produced": p.
```

whenever I try to use the expression `produced[p]` where `p` is a number in `1..5`.

I know that I can create expression arrays with the syntax `dexpr float product[p in products] = (some math expression using p);` but I want to use the form above from my code. It seems this syntax is not allowed for expressions, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
range products = 1..5;

// Variables
dvar float+ P;
dvar float+ Q;

int coefP[products]=
[1,0,1,1,1];
int coefQ[products]=
[0,1,0,1,1];
// Expressions
dexpr float produced[p in products] = coefP[p]*P+coefQ[p]*Q;



subject to
{
  produced[1]==3;
}
```

works fine